# C++ Division Error?

Tags: c++

Hi so whenever I try to do division such as **double x = 3 * (5/10);** it will make x = 0 for some reason. Is there a reason this happens in c++ I'm learning and have no clue why this happens.

Comment: You are doing integer math, with does not have fractional values. 5/10 simply becomes 0 (only the whole part of 0.5 is kept). To have the floating point value, one of you literals has to be of floating point type. 3 * (5.0/10) should work.

Comment: 5/10 is an integer division so the result is 0

Comment: Try this: `double x = 3 * (5.0 / 10.0)` to get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

think about this: what data type is 5?
what data type is 10?
INTEGER!!!

then
(int)5 / (int)10 = (int)0.5 = 0

try this

```
double a = 3;
double b = 5;
double c = 10;
double x = a * (b/c);
```